# Why when compiling .NET Core console application we end up with both dll and exe files?

Tags: .net-core, console-application

I have noticed that both dll and exe files with the name of the project are created on Windows when compiling a .NET Core console application. Why is that? In full .Net framework only the exe file would be created.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Prior to .Net Core 3.0, only the `dll` was created (although you could still do a single file build that was platform-dependent). In these cases you had to use the command `dotnet MyProject.dll` to start your program.

With .Net Core 3.0, they added the `exe`, which is still really just a wrapper around the command above. On other operating systems it also creates an executable file, it just names it `MyProject` instead of `MyProject.exe`

If people have old scripts that still make the dotnet command, this setup doesn't break them, but if you want to just use an `exe`, you can do that too.

Comment: Is there a place in the official documentation that describes this behaviour?

Comment: @mark I think this is probably what you are after https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0#compiledeploy

Comment: @mark for .net core you can actually place all the package metadata in the csproj file rather than creating a separate nuspec file. You can then use the dotnet pack command to generate a package. Additionally you can set the <OutputType> property in the csproj to Library. That will remove the exe. Lastly, you probably don't need to target netcoreappx.y for a nuget package. It is actually better to target netstandard2.0 or netstandard2.1 because then your package will work with any compliant framework. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard